# Retrieving data from the API and displaying in a pie chart

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I have a problem with displaying data downloaded from the API in the form of json. The data is not displayed/refresh in the pie chart, ngx-chart, static data work well. 
I have already read all posts about ngx-chart and Angular, but I have not found a solution to my problem.

Code for ts

```
public memoryapi
  public memoryinfo
  public single =  [
    {
        "name": "",
        "value": 34,

    },

    {
      "name": "Free Memory",
      "value": 8,
  }
];




  ngOnInit(){
    this.getInfo() 


  }



  getInfo() {

    let info;
    info = this.http.get('request to API')
    info.subscribe(listcapacityresponse => {

      this.memoryapi = listcapacityresponse.listcapacityresponse.capacity[0]
      this.single[0].name = this.memoryapi.name
      this.single[0].value = this.memoryapi.percentused


 }

    )}

  view: any[] = [350, 300];

  // options
  showLegend = false;

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28']
  };

  // pie
  showLabels = true;
  explodeSlices = true;
  doughnut = true;


  onSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }


}
```

Template file:

```
<div *ngIf="single > 0"  class="grid-item"> 

    <ngx-charts-pie-chart 
      [view]="view"
      [scheme]="colorScheme"
      [results]="single"
      [legend]="showLegend"
      [explodeSlices]="explodeSlices"
      [labels]="showLabels"
      [doughnut]="doughnut"
      [gradient]="gradient"
      (select)="onSelect($event)">
    </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
  </div>
```

//API RESPONSE

```
{"listcapacityresponse":{"count":10,"capacity":[{"type":0,"name":"MEMORY","zoneid":"5f0d15e3-5937-42f6-95bc-e13f2e15ab9d","zonename":"Sandbox-simulator","capacityallocated":2952790016,"capacityused":2952790016,"capacitytotal":34359738368,"percentused":"8.59"},{"type":1,"name":"CPU","zoneid":"5f0d15e3-5937-42f6-95bc-e13f2e15ab9d","zonename":"Sandbox-simulator","capacityallocated":2500,"capacityused":2500,"capacitytotal":128000,"percentused":"1.95"},{"type":2,"name":"STORAGE","zoneid":"5f0d15e3-5937-42f6-95bc-e13f2e15ab9d","zonename":"Sandbox-simulator","capacityused":0,"capacitytotal":4398046511104,"percentused":"0"},{"type":3,"name":"STORAGE_ALLOCATED","zoneid":"5f0d15e3-5937-42f6-95bc-e13f2e15ab9d","zonename":"Sandbox-simulator","capacityused":138512695596,"capacitytotal":8796093022208,"percentused":"1.57"},{"type":4,"name":"VIRTUAL_NETWORK_PUBLIC_IP","zoneid":"5f0d15e3-5937-42f6-95bc-e13f2e15ab9d","zonename":"Sandbox-simulator","capacityused":3,"capacitytotal":199,"percentused":"1.51"},{"type":5,"name":"PRIVATE_IP","zoneid":"5f0d15e3-5937-42f6-95bc-e13f2e15ab9d","zonename":"Sandbox-simulator","capacityused":6,"capacitytotal":199,"percentused":"3.02"},{"type":6,"name":"SECONDARY_STORAGE","zoneid":"5f0d15e3-5937-42f6-95bc-e13f2e15ab9d","zonename":"Sandbox-simulator","capacityused":0,"capacitytotal":0,"percentused":"0"},{"type":7,"name":"VLAN","zoneid":"5f0d15e3-5937-42f6-95bc-e13f2e15ab9d","zonename":"Sandbox-simulator","capacityused":1,"capacitytotal":101,"percentused":"0.99"},{"type":19,"name":"GPU","zoneid":"5f0d15e3-5937-42f6-95bc-e13f2e15ab9d","zonename":"Sandbox-simulator","capacityused":0,"capacitytotal":0,"percentused":"0"},{"type":90,"name":"CPU_CORE","zoneid":"5f0d15e3-5937-42f6-95bc-e13f2e15ab9d","zonename":"Sandbox-simulator","capacityallocated":4,"capacityused":4,"capacitytotal":16,"percentused":"25"}]}}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Any error messages ?

Comment: Data from the API does not apply to the single variable, i.e. they do not update.

Comment: @Foxx Or try `if(listcapacityresponse){ your code}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue happened to me two years ago. This is the solution. Just change your logic to,

```
  public single =  [];

  ...

  getInfo() {

    let info;
    info = this.http.get('request to API')
    info.subscribe(listcapacityresponse => {

    this.memoryapi = listcapacityresponse.listcapacityresponse.capacity[0]
    this.single = 
     [{
       "name": this.memoryapi.name,
       "value": this.memoryapi.percentused
      },
      {
       "name": "Free Memory",
       "value": 8
      }]
```

You need to initialize your array at once time. Your `*ngIf` usage is correct but its useless in your case because you are already defining your `single`  variable in class definition.